# Error caused by pressing backspace button on the soft keyboard for too long

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a search area (EditText) with `addTextChangedListener`. When an input comes, my `AsyncTask`, which is in `afterTextChanged` method starts up.

- In `onPreExecute` method, the dialog with the message of "please wait" is shown.
- In `doInBackground` method, items are filtered
- In `onPostExecute` method, filtered items are written to the list, after that the "please wait" dialog is stopped.

Suppose that there is a word with 6 characters in the search area. When I press and hold the backspace button on the soft keyboard, characters are deleted one by one quickly.

But in here I get error `IllegalStateException`(the content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification).

Although I use the `notifyDataSetChanged` method in `postExecute`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {    

///forcontrol pressing backeSpace in editText(softKeyboard)

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

                parent.endsWith("");            

                return true;
            } 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution in more detail?

Comment: "parent" is string variable that keep parent activity name